json_normalize from pandas (Python) - how to keep variables high in the parse tree?
I need to convert a .json file to .csv. This file has an extremely complex structure:
"lineItemSourcedId": 218410938,
"ext_inspera_assessmentRunTitle": "SPE1053 Inspera Digital Exam 20 May 2024",
"ext_inspera_assessmentRunExternalId": "EmOkVON97XbA8UczrBcjCAc9kt32VCafDe933mzoTMIYItqgmQdzEtO6O6q2W23k-a6cc1ca5c74b141b8e41e6f8d739ffbfc4d85f18",
"ext_inspera_maxTotalScore": 824,
"ext_inspera_candidates": [
    {
        "result": {
            "sourcedId": 30460745,
            "ext_inspera_userAssessmentSetupId": 33061896,
            "ext_inspera_userAssessmentId": 25160852,
            "dateLastModified": "2024-05-20T10:54:49Z",
            "ext_inspera_startTime": "2024-05-20T08:32:08Z",
            "ext_inspera_endTime": "2024-05-20T10:54:49Z",
            "ext_inspera_extraTimeMins": 0,
            "ext_inspera_incidentTimeMins": 0,
            "ext_inspera_candidateId": "230402199",
            "ext_inspera_attendance": true,
            "lineItem": {
                "sourcedId": 218410938,
                "type": "lineItem"
            },
            "student": {
                "sourcedId": 180533235,
                "type": "user"
            },
            "ext_inspera_autoScore": 65.5,
            "ext_inspera_questions": [
                {
                    "ext_inspera_maxQuestionScore": 1,
                    "ext_inspera_questionId": 210834195,
                    "ext_inspera_questionContentItemId": 207749578,
                    "ext_inspera_questionNumber": "1",
                    "ext_inspera_questionTitle": "Select the word class for the underlined words",
                    "ext_inspera_questionWeight": 1,
                    "ext_inspera_durationSeconds": 24,
                    "ext_inspera_autoScore": 0,
                    "ext_inspera_candidateResponses": [
                        {
                            "ext_inspera_response": "rId5",
                            "ext_inspera_interactionAlternative": "6"
                        }
                    ]
                },

With the following code, I have managed to isolate the data I m interested in. This exists in a dictionary under the key "ext_inspera_candidateResponses";
import os
import pandas as pd


os.chdir("/path/to/directory")

with open("json_file.json") as json_file:
    jd = json.load(json_file)

output = pd.json_normalize(jd,
                       record_path= ["ext_inspera_candidates", "result", 
"ext_inspera_questions", "ext_inspera_candidateResponses"]
                          )

output.to_csv("json_conversion_output.csv")

This produces the following .csv file:

However, this does not capture other key variables higher in the tree. For example, I would like to store "ext_inspera_candidateId" and "ext_inspera_autoScore" leading to the following

I have tried to do this by adding  meta= "ext_inspera_candidateId" but though this creates a column, the variable is blank.
Is there any way to (i) extract key-value pairs low in the parse tree, while (ii) retaining key-value pairs higher in the parse tree?
Thanks

Why are all the ext_inspera_autoScore 1 or 0, not 65.5 like in the JSON?

There is a key of the same name lower in the tree (in the dictionary under  "ext_inspera_questions") (NB probably not a good idea to do this, but I didn't design the json file).

meta is the correct option to use, but it should be a list of paths to those fields.
output = pd.json_normalize(
    jd,
    record_path = ["ext_inspera_candidates", "result", "ext_inspera_questions", "ext_inspera_candidateResponses"],
    meta = [["ext_inspera_candidates", "result", "ext_inspera_candidateId"],
            ["ext_inspera_candidates", "result", "ext_inspera_autoScore"]]
)


That's excellent thanks. I hadn't realised that for "meta" you needed to specify the full path to the variable. This works brilliantly and has saved me a lot of time.
